# R texreg: How can I select the gof statistics to be displayed?

Tags: r, r-s4, texreg

I'm using texreg to produce output tables for panel regressions with plm.  I would like to surpress the output of all gof statistics. That is rather than showing R2, adj R2 and N.  I would like to only show adj R2.  Does anyone know of a simple way to do this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Provide sample input data and show exactly which commands you are running and how you are running them. That will make it easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, this was actually pretty easy. Just include the following arguments in the call of `texreg`:

`include.rsquared = F, include.adjrs = TRUE, include.nobs = F`

E.g.:

```
screenreg(model.list, include.rsquared = F, include.adjrs = TRUE, include.nobs = F)
```

Comment: Great! The `?texreg` was a bit vague here: "To omit GOF entries instead of coefficient entries, use the custom arguments of the extract functions instead." -- it wasn't clear where to specify custom arguments to `extract`...

Comment: For future reference: one can get the list of all arguments to include/exclude goodness-of-fit metrics by looking at the signatures of functions in the help page of `?extract`.

Comment: Just FYI, the help page instructions say: (1) run `showMethods('extract')` to get a list of the methods, e.g., `lm`, `felm`, `glm`, then (2) run `getMethod('extract', 'felm')` to show the function definition to find all of the arguments for that method. For instance, one unique argument for `felm` is `include.groups`.