# Remove GOF rows from texreg regression table

Tags: r, texreg

How can you remove gof rows from a texreg table? In my specific case, I'd like to remove the R<sup>2</sup>, Adj. R<sup>2</sup>, and F statistic rows.

I'm using texreg version 1.37.5 and R version 4.1.1. The default table rows I get  from texreg in addition to headings and coefficients are R<sup>2</sup>, Adj. R<sup>2</sup>, Num. obs., and RMSE.

The answer here ([R texreg: How can I select the gof statistics to be displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671966/r-texreg-how-can-i-select-the-gof-statistics-to-be-displayed)) is implemented in the code below but does not work. Possibly the package changed in the last few years since this response was posted.

A look at the texreg documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/texreg/versions/1.37.5/topics/texreg), under the `omit.coef` section, indicates that you can remove gof rows using `extract` but the link is broken.

**SSCCE:**

```
library(estimatr)
library(texreg)

set.seed(42)
x1 <- rnorm(1000)
x2 <- rnorm(1000)
y <- 0.5*x1 + x2 + rnorm(1000)

mod1 <- lm_robust(y ~ x1)
mod2 <- lm_robust(y ~ x1 + x2)

texreg(list(mod1, mod2), 
       include.rsquared = FALSE, 
       include.adjrs = FALSE)
```

Comment: The parameters in textreg() function already exclude R^2 , adj. R^2 and F. I don't get your question.

Comment: agree with @ArielSC; in addition to the coefs I get rows for number of obs and for RMSE. Can you show the output you're getting?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify versions and default output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on `texreg` version 1.37.5.

Observe that the objects are of class `lm_robust`:

```r
> class(mod1)
## [1] "lm_robust"
```

You can display the help page for the corresponding `extract` method as follows:

```r
?extract.lm_robust

## [..]
##
## extract.lm_robust(
##   model,
##   include.ci = TRUE,
##   include.rsquared = TRUE,
##   include.adjrs = TRUE,
##   include.nobs = TRUE,
##   include.fstatistic = FALSE,
##   include.rmse = TRUE,
##   include.nclusts = TRUE,
##   ...
##   )
##
## [...]
```

In your example, you can get rid of all GOF rows as follows:

```r
screenreg(list(mod1, mod2),
  include.rsquared = FALSE,
  include.adjrs = FALSE,
  include.nobs = FALSE,
  include.rmse = FALSE)

## =========================================
##              Model 1        Model 2      
## -----------------------------------------
## (Intercept)   -0.01          -0.00       
##              [-0.10; 0.08]  [-0.07; 0.06]
## x1             0.49 *         0.48 *     
##              [ 0.40; 0.58]  [ 0.41; 0.54]
## x2                            0.98 *     
##                             [ 0.92; 1.05]
## =========================================
## * Null hypothesis value outside the confidence interval.
```

Change from `screenreg` to `texreg` to get LaTeX output. Leave out the last two arguments to get rid of only R-squared and adjusted R-squared. The F-statistic is not reported by default. (Perhaps you used an old version of `texreg`?)

To remove statistics without using those arguments, you can also save `texreg` objects into intermediate objects and manipulate them before you hand them over to the respective table layout function, like in the following example:

```r
tr1 <- extract(mod1)
tr1@gof.names <- tr1@gof.names[-(1:2)]
tr1@gof.decimal <- tr1@gof.decimal[-(1:2)]
tr1@gof <- tr1@gof[-(1:2)]
screenreg(list(tr1, mod2))

## =========================================
##              Model 1        Model 2      
## -----------------------------------------
## (Intercept)   -0.01          -0.00      
##              [-0.10; 0.08]  [-0.07; 0.06]
## x1             0.49 *         0.48 *    
##              [ 0.40; 0.58]  [ 0.41; 0.54]
## x2                            0.98 *    
##                             [ 0.92; 1.05]
## -----------------------------------------
## Num. obs.    1000           1000         
## RMSE            1.41           1.03      
## R^2                            0.53      
## Adj. R^2                       0.53      
## =========================================
## * Null hypothesis value outside the confidence interval.
```

This requires a bit more effort but gives you full control and is applicable also if you want to change only some of the models.

Comment: From sessionInfo(): I'm using texreg version 1.37.5. R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10). Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit). Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.3.1. The code at the bottom of your answer using extract(mod1) works, thank you! Oddly, the code above using include.rsquared=F etc. did not work, but after restarting Rstudio it does. I'll play around a bit more and see if I can recreate the previous odd behavior. Possibly it was an unexpected package interaction?

Comment: I would advise against abbreviating `TRUE` with `T` and `FALSE` with `F` because it is easy to overwrite `T` and `F` with other values. Could this be the reason? Just guessing.

Comment: I tried `?extract.lm_robust` but I get `No documentation for ‘extract.lm_robust’`? Thanks!

Comment: I think the `extract` method for `lm_robust` objects is defined in the `estimatr` package. You need to load this package to have access to the help page. The `estimatr` package enhances the `texreg` package by providing an `extract` method for their `lm_robust` class.